# Label set to visible not showing

Tags: java, html, wicket

I have added a label inside a container in my class which is then set to not viable, I have a onSubmit method that contains if statements. This is where the label should now be visible when it hits one. However it is not showing up.

```
    private Component errorMessage;

    @Override
        protected void onInitialize() {
            super.onInitialize();
        WebMarkupContainer cnt = new WebMarkupContainer("cnt");
            cnt.setOutputMarkupId(true);
        errorMessage = new Label("errorMessageData", "Can not enter a weekend 
        Date, Please enter a weekday").setOutputMarkupId(true);
        cnt.add(errorMessage);
        errorMessage.setVisible(false);
        add(cnt);

public InputForm(String id, final WebMarkupContainer cnt) {

            IndicatingAjaxSubmitLink submitMcb = new IndicatingAjaxSubmitLink("submit") {

                @Override
                protected void onSubmit(AjaxRequestTarget target, Form<?> form) {                       
                            if (!DateUtilities.isWorkDay(mcEntity.getCorrectionDate())) {

                                errorMessage.setVisible(true);
                                return;
                            }
                        }
```

I shortened the code and removed relevant parts for readability. The label shows correctly and in the correct place if I dont set it to false, but setting it to false in the if statement does not remove it. What I'm I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your label to the AjaxRequestTarget to reflect the changes you made:

```
[...]
errorMessage.setVisible(true);
target.add(errorMessage);
return;
```

Comment: target.add(errorMessage); gives me an error, 'can not resolve method'

Comment: It seems you use very old version of Wicket. `addComponent()` has been renamed to just `add()` in Wicket 1.4.0 or 1.5.0, I don't remember exactly.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what @Joachim Rohde said you need to replace `errorMessage.setOutputMarkupId(true);` with `errorMessage.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);` because you start with an invisible state.

Comment: Thanks, that might explain why it was hiding when setting it to false but not the other way around!!